# In Rails, is there a way to create a new independent transaction inside the current one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Inside a longer transaction with many operations i need to make a small select with a lock. But i don't want the lock to last as long as the main transaction. So i'm guessing if there is a way to make this select outside the main transaction.

Something like this:

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
     david.withdrawal(100)
     mary.deposit(100)
     ... (more stuff)
     ActiveRecord::Base.new_transaction do
       generic_indentifier.next_with_increment_and_lock
     end
     ... (more stuff)
   end
```

I've used this aproach many times In J2EE using for example Springs's Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW or some JPA equivalents.

But i haven't found this possibility in Rails. Is there a way to achieve this?

The requires_new: option does not fit my requirements because it starts a nested transaction inside the current one, so the lock will last until the main transaction ends.

The solution will probably need to use a new pool connection. Any idea?

Comment: No, this is not what i need, requires_new creates a nested transaction, not a independent one.  'requires_new: If this is set to true then the block will be wrapped in a database savepoint acting as a sub-transaction.'

Answer (score 0):

Rails transactions have 2 optional mechanisms:

- `requires_new`:  Controls whether this transaction will join the parent transaction
- `joinable`: Controls whether or not child transactions will join this transaction

In this case it appears you are looking for `requires_new: true` to create a separate transaction inside a parent transaction.

For Example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do # CREATES A SAVEPOINT
    generic_indentifier.next_with_increment_and_lock
  end # RELEASE or ROLLBACK depending on outcome of the transaction
end
```

<sub>Note: No RDBMSs, other than MSSQL, actually support "nested transactions" so AR emulates this with the SAVEPOINT implementation</sub>

Comment: No, this is not what i need, requires_new creates a nested transaction, not a independent one. 'requires_new: If this is set to true then the block will be wrapped in a database savepoint acting as a sub-transaction.'

Comment: @RicardoVila this is a new transaction. The save point is merely to ensure ROLLBACK of the inner transaction if it fails. This transaction will operate fully independent of the parent transaction whichbis what you are requesting. I would recommend actually trying it rather than relying on your interpretation of the wording in the documentation.

Comment: Indeed it is, but using the same conection, so the locking in the inner transaction will last as long as the outer transaction. This is why i need another aproach, a new independent transaction.

Comment: @RicardoVila have you confirmed that the lock actually lasts as long as the outer transaction? If so the only other way I can think of, that *might* work is to spawn a new thread, inside that thread you can use ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection to obtain a new connection, run your transaction, then join the thread back in.

Comment: We had implemented one similar solution developing an API call lo localhost to do the inner transaction.  But this is an aproach we try to avoid. In J2EE Spring i  know you can doit with the REQUIRES_NEW and i was wondering if there were a Rails equivalent. Maybe not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly stumbled on this and wanted to offer up an idea that probably has its own downsides, if it even works: Using ruby threads.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
  rollback = false
  Thread.new do
    Rails.application.executor.wrap do
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do # CREATES A SAVEPOINT
        generic_indentifier.next_with_increment_and_lock
        rollback = true if some_decision
      end
    end
  end.join
  trigger_rollback if rollback
end
```

Comment: Interesting aproach. I'm not sure if it will preserve execution order. I'll try it